# jQuery .validate() plugin, additional method to validate numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

A while ago I've written a custom validation method for [.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). It is a local validation plugin, with some limited validation.

I was required to write a validation method with the following requirements:

- Must accept a custom string.
- Must allow a maximum value.
- Must allow a minimum value.
- Has to allow to have dynamic values on the string.
- Must validate using a regular expression.
- Must allow numbers in the Portuguese and English formats.

At the time, it was quite a challenge and I was happy with the result, but the code is **BAD**. It works, but it is so hacky and kludged it hurts my soul.

```
(function(){
    var __c_number_between=new String('');

        __c_number_between.valueOf=function(){
                return 'The value must be between __MIN__ and __MAX__'
                    .replace(/__MIN__/g,this.min)
                    .replace(/__MAX__/g,this.max);
            };
        __c_number_between.toString=function(){return this.valueOf();};

    $.validator.addMethod('c_number_between',
        function(d,i,o){
            var num=d.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.')/1;
            __c_number_between.min=o.min;
            __c_number_between.max=o.max;
            return o.max>=num&&num>=o.min;
        },__c_number_between);
})();
```

Yes, that is *the* code. It fulfills all my needs, but relies on a really bad behaviour in Javascript, which is that objects are passed as a reference. It also relies on Javascript being executed linearly, instead of having multiple threads, which is REALLY bad!

How can I re-write this in a clean and decent way?

---

<sub>Also, worth noticing is that this is a cross-posting from StackOverflow, on the following question: [jQuery .validation plugin: help cleaning aditional method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884720/jquery-validation-plugin-help-cleaning-aditional-method)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery.validator.format()

jQuery.validator has a [format method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format)

This allows you to replace the String  you created entirely.

However, this would require you to replace your 'o' parameter object with an array ( [min,max] ).

```
$.validator.addMethod('c_number_between',
    function(d,i,o){
        var num=d.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.')/1,
            // min/max assigns for context readability (optional)
            min = o[0],
            max = o[1];
        return max>=num&&num>=min;
    },$.validator.format('The value must be between {0} and {1}'));
```

## Update:

While the docs say:

> The default message to display for this method. Can be a function created by ''jQuery.validator.format(value)''. When undefined, an existing message is used (handy for localization), otherwise the field-specific messages have to be defined.

Any function that returns a string can be used so boom:

```
$.validator.addMethod('c_number_between',
    function(d,i,o){
        var num=d.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',','.')/1,
        return 0.max>=num&&num>=0.min;
    },function(params){return 'The value must be between {0} and {1}'.replace('{0}',params.min).replace('{1}',params.max);});
```

Comment: Actually, it is `o.max` and `o.min`, instead of `o[0]` and `o[1]`. But other than that... WOW! I had no idea about that method. It really is a lifesaver! Thank you a lot! Now, I have a few validations to fix. Once again, thank you

Comment: To use $.validator.format the o parameter has to be an array (as far as i know) so {min:y,max: x} is now [x,y]... aleast in how i interpreted your code

Comment: That would be a bad surprise. It isn't feasable to change everything. I have at least 100 instances of that validation. But that is a problem outside the scope of your review, and something I didn't mention. Therefore, you deserved the reputation. I will look into some way to hammer this screw on my steel bar.